# ScrollView won't populate

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview

I have a ListView that gets data from Firestore, puts it all into an ArrayList of type UserItem and then puts that into the adapter to be shown.

Problem is that for some reason, it refuses to show anything.

I have tried a couple of things like implementing .notifyOnSetChanged() but to no avail (More than sure I didn't do it properly, it's deleted in the code below).

How do I fix this?

UserItem (The class for every item in the ListView):

```
package com.example.create4me;

public class UserItem {
    String username, timestamp, offerID, isComplete;
    public UserItem(String username, String timestamp, String offerID, String isComplete){
        this.username = username;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.offerID = offerID;
        this.isComplete = isComplete;
    }
    public String getUsername(){
        return this.username;
    }
    public String getTimestamp(){
        return this.timestamp;
    }
    public String getOfferID(){
        return this.offerID;
    }
    public String getIsComplete(){
        return this.isComplete;
    }
}
```

UserAdapter (The adapter for the ListView):

```
package com.example.create4me;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserItem> {
    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UserItem> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        UserItem user = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.userlayout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userlayoutUsername);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userlayoutTimestamp);
        TextView isComplete = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.isComplete);
        username.setText(user.getUsername());
        timestamp.setText(user.getTimestamp());
        isComplete.setText(user.getIsComplete());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The activity responsible to show the items to the user:

```
package com.example.create4me;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyCreatedOfferActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView image, profilepic;
    TextView madeBy, title, desc, price;
    String offerid, madyByUuid;
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private static final long ONE_MB = 1024 * 1024;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    StorageReference ref = storage.getReference();
    FirebaseUser user;
    Button backToHome;
    String madeByUsername = "";
    ListView usersListView;
    ArrayList<UserItem> usersList;
    UsersAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_created_offer);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        Intent data = getIntent();
        offerid = data.getExtras().getString("offerID");
        image = findViewById(R.id.OfferActivityImage);
        backToHome = findViewById(R.id.backToHomeButton);
        //profilepic = findViewById(R.id.OfferActivityProfileImage);
        title = findViewById(R.id.OfferActivityTitle);
        desc = findViewById(R.id.OfferActivityDescription);
        price = findViewById(R.id.OfferActivityPrice);
        madeBy = findViewById(R.id.OfferActivityCreatorName);

        //Over here, we create the List and also get the container for the ListView
        usersListView = findViewById(R.id.listcontainer);
        usersList = new ArrayList<UserItem>();

        //Here we get the data from Firestore
        getData();

        //Here we put the data into the adapter so it could be populated, but isn't
        adapter = new UsersAdapter(this, usersList);
        usersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        backToHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyCreatedOfferActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        loadData();
    }
    public void getData(){
        db.collection("ongoing")
                .whereEqualTo("creatorID", user.getUid())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()){
                                usersList.add(new UserItem(doc.getData().get("buyerUsername").toString(),
                                              doc.getData().get("timestamp").toString(),
                                              doc.getData().get("offerID").toString(),
                                              doc.getData().get("isComplete").toString()));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    public void loadData(){
        db.collection("offers")
                .whereEqualTo("offerID", offerid.toString())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()){
                                title.setText(doc.getData().get("title").toString());
                                desc.setText(doc.getData().get("description").toString());
                                price.setText(doc.getData().get("price").toString());
                                madeBy.setText(doc.getData().get("madeByName").toString());
                                madyByUuid = doc.getData().get("madeByID").toString();
                                StorageReference imageref = ref.child(doc.getData().get("image").toString());
                                imageref.getBytes(ONE_MB).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                        // Handle any errors
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        db.collection("users")
                .whereEqualTo("uuid", madyByUuid)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                            StorageReference imageref = ref.child(doc.getData().get("profilePic").toString());
                            imageref.getBytes(ONE_MB).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                    profilepic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    // Handle any errors
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Edit: Someone asked for the XML file, so here it is (Yes it's ugly af but works for now):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyCreatedOfferActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/backToHomeButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back to home"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/OfferActivityImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OfferActivityTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/OfferActivityPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="price"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/OfferActivityProfileImage"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Made By:"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/OfferActivityCreatorName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="name"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="17dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OfferActivityDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listcontainer"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/OfferActivityDescription"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you also post the xml where the view is set? I have had such trouble and sometimes it has been due to some problem with constraints that sets the width or height to 0.

Comment: What does `user.getUsername()` return inside your adapter? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo the user.getUsername() gets the username from the object that is set for every element in the ListView. Look in the UserItem, the function is there.

Comment: If you log the result is it what  you want?

Comment: @AlexMamo what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You populate the userList after the query to your DB is done. But, from the moment that it's done in another thread, the main UI thread keeps going, so you basically pass an empty arrayList in your adapter, as by the time the userList is filled, you've already shown your UI.
To solve this, you should wrap the db request inside a new thread, and once that the request is finished, move to the UI thread to populate the layout.

Here a very basic example:

```
new Thread(() -> {

    //Make the request to your DB, but NOT by using any type of asynchronous method, 
    //as you are already in a separate and secure thread, so you don't need it.


    //Just and example. When you query your DB, is always better to get the most out of a single transaction, 
    //so that you don't have to query it multiple times for very little informations.
    ArrayList<UserItem> userList = getUserItemList();

    //Now that you have all the data that you need, you can move to the UIThread

    runOnUiThread(() -> {
        //I just copied your code for setting up the ScrollView
        adapter = new UsersAdapter(this, usersList);
        usersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    });


}).start();
```

Comment: Pretty sure I did something wrong, this is what I did (https://pastebin.com/1n2p0cgE).
This is something new to me so more than certain I implemented it wrong, I put it in the onCreate method. @Ekiden

Comment: @qwirrr if you didn’t change the getData() function you’ll still have the same problem. You can either put the runOnUiThread inside the onComplete method provided by the listener, but it’s not a very good practice, or manage to do the db query in that separate thread, without using another one as seems you’re doing with the getData method. Probably the first solution is the easier to implement, but the second will give you a much cleaner code.

Comment: Ok I legit feel so retarded right now, it worked with that thread inside the onComplete. But then I realized I logged into the wrong test account xD